# Force https performance

Tags: ssl

How can i force https on my site without affecting performance.

I'm presently using mod_rewrite in .htaccess and it seems to be impacting performance of the site.

Comment: I don't think this is due to implementing solution http://security.stackexchange.com/a/43377/30521 but rather that HTTPS itself is an expensive protocol relative to HTTP. A permanent redirect is only processed once per browser/unique visitor

Comment: Yes. This is probably a SuperUser stack exchange question. Side note: Check that your Apache hasn't been [configured](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrandomseed) to use `/dev/random` instead of `/dev/urandom`. As without a hardware TRNG this `/dev/random` can block and delay quite a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/q/43376/2630? (which has more context). David, you do not have to use Apache... you can also use nginx which has a very clean configuration syntax. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html if you want to switch.

Answer (score 1):

ssl will always affect performance, but there are some ways to boost your ssl-performance:

- use a [HSTS-Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) in `<virtualhost:443>` - config
- ssl-cache & keepalive reduces load by reducing the number of ssl-handshakes
- search and check different cipher-suites regarding performance
- gzip / expires can be used to speed up page-load and reduce traffic(http-compression != ssl-compression)
- [more advises here](http://www.mare-system.de/guide-to-nginx-ssl-spdy-hsts/#optimizing-for-better-ssl-performance); those are for nginx, but might be converted to apache
- [performance-tuning](http://unhandledexpression.com/2013/01/25/5-easy-tips-to-accelerate-ssl/) for ssl-cipher-suites (untested by me)

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the SPDY protocol, which provides security and high performance. It's not supported much in IE yet, but will help users of most other browsers.

Comment: Apache does not ship with this module by default, the performance issue that OP is describing is not related to HTTPS on its own, but premature optimization / stupid configuration.